# Visifire line charts

Tags: silverlight, linechart, google-finance, visifire

I have a visifire line chart in my silver light project. There are some data points ( lets say 5).

I need to show the Y value when I mouse over between the data points .

Is there any way to implement this using visifire?.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll want to create a tooltip.

In your XAML, it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: hi Randy,Yes I am getting the tool tip with Y value in all the data points. But I need get it when the mouse go through in between data points.

Comment: "go through in between"? - What does this mean?

Comment: The line between data points. ie at any point I need to get the Y value as tooltip

Comment: @Prasadthankappan - You're only going to be able to get tooltips for actual data points. For example, let's say you have two data points in your chart, and a line connects those data points. Even though the line connecting these data points might be long, you only actually have two data points. Therefore, you're only going to be able to see two tooltips, not for every pixel on the line.

Comment: ok.. but my requirement is to show the tooltip in everywhere in the line.. So is there any way to achieve this?